# Can I change email notification new user Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

When I test my registration as new user or when I want to change this mail I get notification email

> To set your password, visit the following address:

I found it in my wordpress file twice and I changed it to
`/class-subscribes.php` and `/pluggable.php`

```
    $message .= __('To set your password, visit the following address:') . "\r\n\r\n";
```

and I find another location in the database and when I change it I don't receive any message if I make a registration

Comment: Side note, you never want to change the WP core files

Comment: if I want to change this mail what i can do?

Comment: As @jo8691 pointed out, don't change the core WP files. You can either use a plugin, such as SB Welcome Email Editor, or use the wp_new_user_notification[https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_new_user_notification/] filter in the functions.php file of your theme.

Comment: You can edit the email message through the filter "wp_new_user_notification_email" in pluggable.php, but you will need some regex / substring processes first to extract the set password link.